# Could a large enough semi isolated population keep up with Eurasia in technology?

Tags: medieval, alternate-history, technological-development, civilization, alternate-reality

Could a  semi-isolated country  island  about 3,000,000 square miles and 1000 miles south of India avoid becoming a colony and develop into a rich and strong modern state today? 
They have about the same technology level as the Ottoman empire.  Guns, cannons, shipbuilding skills, and a population of about 100 million.

Comment: so Australia then.

Comment: Welcome! How many people live on the island? Which level is their technology? Why are using imperial units for the surface and SI units for the distance? Who is attempting colonization? Which technology do they have? Please provide these additional info. Then take a look at the [help] and take the [tour] to better know our community.

Comment: 3 million square miles is 7.7 million square kilometers. For comparison, the European Union (complete with the United Kingdom) has an area of 4.4 million square kilometeres. That's not an island, that's a continent. And a continent with a civilization level which only allows for one trading expedition per year won't be able to resist colonization or, more likely, outright conquest. Plus not sure what *"able to resist colonization"* even means. There were Italian colonies in Wallachia; Transylvania still has Germans, and one of them is president of Romania; there are Albanians in Italy; etc.

Comment: Welcome.  You're asking two 3 different questions.  Your title asks if a large semi-isolated population could keep up with Eurasia in tech.  But the body of the posts asks 1) can the island avoid becoming a colony and 2) if it can develop into a rich and strong modern state.  It is possible for a country to be all of those things, none of those things, or any 1 or 2 of those things.  So pick one.

Comment: A colony of what ?  Of a huge empire with a massive hi-tech army and airforce or of a similar sized similarly populated, similarly teched nation ?  How badly does the colonizer want it ?  There's no end of variables here and you have even outlined the top points.

Answer (score 3):

Consider Japan during the *Age of Exploration*. This example suggests that the key was not geographic isolation but a strong government that could and did reject contact.

In *Medieval* times, there were even more countries which managed to resist colonization. An interesting question here is if the spread of Christianity and Islam would be colonization. Consider Persia.

Comment: Colonization by definition implies the existence of *colonists*. The spread of the French ideas about the separation of legislative, judicial and executive powers does not mean that France sent colonists to Japan or Argentina.

Comment: @AlexP: I don't think so.  Consider India as a British colony. British people went there as administrators, soldiers, & technicians.  They might spend a few years there, or an entire career, but they would eventually return "Home".  Few if any went there with the intention of settling there permanently.

Comment: @jamesqf: *"Few if any went there with the intention of settling there permanently":* which makes it **not** a colony. India was one of the states of the British Empire, with a rather complicated relationship with the United Kingdom. The two countries were in personal union (the king/queen of England being emperor/empress of India), and India functioned more or less as an overly large protectorate. India had its own international personality (e.g., it was one of the founding states of the League of Nations), was fully integrated in the politics and globalized economy of the B.E. and so on.

Comment: @AlexP: But you seem to be using your own definition of colony, not the one used by all the people to whom British India is a prime example of colonialism - and the places where the British did go to settle, like Canada, Australia, and New Zealand, generally aren't.

Comment: @jamesqf: [Colonialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonialism) ≠ [colonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization). Colonialism is the policy of a nation seeking to extend or retain its authority over other people or territories, generally with the aim of economic dominance. Colonization refers strictly to migration, for example, to settler colonies in America or Australia. (Both from Wikipedia.) Both the original question and this answer refer to *colonization*.